# Ubuntu 12.04/14.04 - apt-get 404 Not Found [IP: local-dns-server-ip 80] through proxy

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-12.04, apt, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to setup an ubuntu server (12.04 or 14.04) and have installed the server image onto the system I am using.

Everything works fine until I try to run `sudo apt-get update`. When this runs, I keep getting 404 errors.

`W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/universe/source/Sources 404 Not Found [IP: 10.0.0.101 80]`

Also note that the IP address in the `[IP: 10.0.0.101 80]` part is our local DNS server.

This is repeated for all sources, the above is just one of the many occurrences.

When running an install eg. `apt-get install phpmyadmin`, I get another error.

`E: Unable to locate package phpmyadmin`

Note that we use a proxy like system to authenticate the internet connection, which I have setup as a proxy and appears to be working. When removing the proxy, I then get a different error from running `apt-get update`.

I have tried this on both 12.04 and 14.04, both give the exact same error message as shown above.

I have tried updating `sources.list` to point to `archive.ubuntu.com` instead of `gb.archive.ubuntu.com` and had no luck there.

The server also has a static ip configuration, but the error is the same if not using a static ip.

I am able to ping out from the server with success.

The proxy configuration in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` is as follows.

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "https://domain.local/username:password@10.0.0.1:4100";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "https://domain.local/username:password@10.0.0.1:4100";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://domain.local/username:password@10.0.0.1:4100";
```

I am rather stuck as what to do next and have been unable to find anything related browsing Google and on here, so any help is much appreciated.

If any more information is required (eg, log files), let me know and I will add them to the post.

Thanks,
Joe

**Update:**

I have tried changing the name servers used to 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4. When doing this, I then get an `domain.local not found` error. I then added this to my `etc/hosts` file, which fixed that error. But when running the update, I still get a 404 error, just this time without any ip address on the end.

Comment: What I understand is the error is in the apache2 itself .. if so, can you check if the server is listening to port 80? `netstat -an` and `telnet localhost 80`